# Why does Shift+0 on my keyboard produce unexpected "=:" characters?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Today my keyboard works unexpectedly.For example

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> = `:=`
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> = `" "` (no character displayed)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> = `" "` (no character displayed)

I displayed the onscreen keyboard for identifying the pressed button but I haven't seen any button being pressed. Also my keyboard localization is still the same in Windows 7.

I am going to mad. How can identify problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: What? Please improve your question. What are you trying to do? What is the current result? What is your expected result?

Comment: I'm guessing he's saying that if he taps the shift key and then releases it then presses another key it reacts as though he were still holding down the shift key. Since the on screen keyboard doesn't show the extra keystroke  (a clever debug on his part)I'm guessing this is sticky keys.

Comment: oh, makes since, I had no idea what he was talking about.

Comment: I am sorry for all of you for late answer now i tried to improve my question and i hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Your keyboard is broken, buy a new one. Have you accidentally pour some water/coffee in it? Maybe ask your family member if they've done that.

Comment: @gunbuster363 - it is actualy happened while i am using.Still i am thinking that it is about settings. now i will try it on ubuntu os.

Comment: Worked same on ubuntu too :( it looks problem on hardware

Comment: The water pour into the keyboard will mess up the keyboard's circuit. So the signal from your keyboard went to nowhere.

Comment: @gunbuster363 - i am really sory for my sucked english i haven't tried to say that i accidentally pour some water into my keyboard. I just wanted to say my keyboard started to work unexpectedly while using it. Now my keyboard is working normal and i didn't change anything. There may be some wiring problem inside hardware. Now do i have to vote to delete question , accept any answer or leave question without accept any answer ?

Comment: @Freshblood Don't accept an answer that didn't help you. If you leave the question open people might come to it later and don't see you actually solved it. But: You can answer your own question and accept this answer in 2 days from now.

Comment: SO you keyboard got something wrong, it is broken anyway. One day it is good and one day it is broken, conclusion? It is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the revision to your question, this is truly bizarre. If you're certain it's not localisation settings, and you're not seeing any continually pressed keys, then that eliminates most of the usual suspects of this behavior.

I can only think of a couple things to try without having it in front of me:

Hold down the windows key and press 'r'

type **intl.cpl** and then press ENTER.

On the Keyboards and Language tab, try switching to a similar a similar layout and see if this helps.

If that doesn't help try toggling sticky keys and see what it does:

Click the Start button,

click Control Panel,

click Ease of Access,

click Ease of Access Center,

click Make the keyboard easier to use.

Turn off Sticky keys.

If neither of these has any effect, then you have either a rare hardware malfunction or strangely pointless malware.

Comment: I think it is not because of sticky keys...

Answer (score 0):

As the OP confirmed he got some water into the keyboard recently. I am pretty sure the circuit in the keyboard was mess up by the water.

In this case, some signal from the keys may go to anywhere become the signal went through the water. The signal went to nowhere, so there aren't any response.

The keyboard is broken. If the liquid is only water, try to place the keyboard upside down so that the water can come out. You keyboard become normal again after time, or it is already broken.